# handleActionWithIdentifier doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uilocalnotification

I use UILocalNotification in one app and in iOS 7 or earlier is working fine, but in iOS 8 didReceiveLocalNotification is not being called at all.
After some research I found out that in iOS 8 we have to use handleActionWithIdentifier instead, and so I tried it but also this void is not being called when LocalNotification run.
Here is my code:

I've got this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and it works ok, first time I launched the app I've been asked permission to give notifications etc.

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

Then I got:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings  *)notificationSettings
  {
   //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
   }

  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
     NSLog(@"handleAction");
}


 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

{

 }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
 {
      NSLog(@"didReceive");
 }
```

When the localNotification run and I slide my finger on the message that appears on the screen nothing happens... logs are not called at all...
I also noticed that if the app is active and running, when the localNotification run, it get called the method didReceiveLocalNotification
Anyone know what am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

add this to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

You forgot to add this line:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];`

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

According to the Apple documentation of `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:`:

> Your implementation of this method should perform the action associated with the specified identifier and execute the block in the completionHandler parameter as soon as you are done. Failure to execute the completion handler block at the end of your implementation will cause your app to be terminated.

Your implementation above is missing the completion handler block.

To make it work, modify your `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:` to be as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
     NSLog(@"handleAction");
     if (completionHandler) {
         completionHandler();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method calle when the user taps a custom action in the alert for a remote or local notification’s.

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandle 
{
//some action
}
```

When you slide finger on screen called this method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I see you are handling the "`forRemoteNotification:`" case, 
I don't see this being defined in your original block of code:

[`application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:)

Comment: Ok, I changed my code with: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
  completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler  but still nothing happens...